# Entity Framework Core Related Data with custom result table

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

My project is  Power Plant Budget Control System with asp.net core 1.1
My Models is look like this:

```
 public class BudgetAuthority
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string  AuthorityName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<REHPViewModelData> REHPData { get; set; }
    }

public class BudgetHead
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string BudgetHeadName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string BudgetHeadDescription { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<REHPViewModelData> REHPData { get; set; }
    }

public class BudgetYear
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string BudgetYearName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<BudgetYearlyAllocation> BudgetYearlyAllocation { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<REHPViewModelData> REHPData { get; set; }
    }

public class BudgetYearlyAllocation
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]
        public decimal AllocatedAmount { get; set; }

        public int BudgetYearID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("BudgetYearID")]
        public virtual BudgetYear BudgetYear { get; set; }

         public int PowerPlantID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("PowerPlantID")]
        public virtual PowerPlants PowerPlants { get; set; }
    }



public class PowerPlants
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string PowerPlantName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<REHPViewModelData> REHPData { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<BudgetYearlyAllocation> BudgetYearlyAllocation { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
public class WorkCategories
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string WorkCategoriesName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<REHPViewModelData> REHPData { get; set; }
    }

public class REHPViewModelData
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }                         
        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]
        public decimal ApprovedAmount { get; set; }


        public int PowerPlantID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("PowerPlantID")]
        public virtual PowerPlants PowerPlants { get; set; }

        public int BudgetHeadID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("BudgetHeadID")]
        public virtual BudgetHead BudgetHead { get; set; }      

        public int WorkCategoriesID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("WorkCategoriesID")]
        public virtual WorkCategories WorkCategories { get; set; }        

        public int AuthorityID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("AuthorityID")]
        public virtual BudgetAuthority BudgetAuthority { get; set; }

        public int BudgetYearID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("BudgetYearID")]
        public virtual BudgetYear BudgetYear { get; set; }
    }
```

Example  BudgetAuthority Table data is

```
ID  AuthorityName
1   MD
2   GM
```

Example BudgetHead Table data is

```
ID  BudgetHeadName  BudgetHeadDescription
1   A/budget            Travelling for Plan
2   B/budget            Travelling for Car
3   C/budget            Travelling for Shipping
```

Example  BudgetYear Table data is

```
ID  BudgetYearName
1   2017
2   2018
3   2019
```

Example BudgetYearlyAllocation Table data is

```
ID  AllocatedAmount     BudgetYearID    PowerPlantID
1   1000                1       1
2   900             1       2
3   800             1       3
```

Example  PowerPlants Table Data is

```
ID      PowerPlantName
1   PowerStationOne
2   PowerStationTwo
3   PowerStationThree
```

Example WorkCategories Table data is

```
ID  WorkCategoriesName
1   Electrical
2   Civil
3   Mechanical
4   General
```

I want  Table result of  Only Budget years and  power plant  data details Table data example ind sql database data is

```
 ID (1)BudgetYearIDColumn (2)PowerPlantIDColumn     (3)TotalElectricalAmountColumn    (4)Nos    (5)TotalMechnicalColumn  (6)Nos  (7) TotalCivilColumn    (8)Nos (6)TotalGeneralColumn  (9)Nos   (10)TotalAmountColumn  (11) AllocatedAmountOfBudgetYearlyAllocationTablewithPowerPlantID – (10)TotalAmount Column   (12)MDAuthorityNosColumn  (13)GMAuthorityNosColumn

  1     1   1   100     3   100  2  200  1  100  5  500  1000-500=500    8   3
  2     1   2   100     3   100  2  200  1  100  5  500  900-500=400     8   3
  3     1   3   100     3   100  2  200  1  100  5  500  800-500=300     8   3
```

Index.chtml result is looklike this-

```
ID (1)BudgetYearIDColumn (2)PowerPlantIDColumn      (3)TotalElectricalAmountColumn    (4)Nos    (5)TotalMechnicalColumn  (6)Nos  (7) TotalCivilColumn    (8)Nos (6)TotalGeneralColumn  (9)Nos   (10)TotalAmountColumn  (11) AllocatedAmountOfBudgetYearlyAllocationTablewithPowerPlantID – (10)TotalAmount Column   (12)MDAuthorityNosColumn  (13)GMAuthorityNosColumn

 1     2017 PowerPlantOne   100.00     3    100.00   2  200.00   1  100.00   5  500.00   500.00    8   3

 2     2017 PowerPlantTwo   100.00     3    100.00   2  200.00   1  100.00   5  500.00   400.00    8   3
 3     2017 PowerPlantThree 100.00     3    100.00   2  200.00   1  100.00   5  500.00   300.00    8   3
```

Please help me this result table can be show in REHPViewModelData
Model and  REHPViewModelData is not include BudgetAllocation table with not relationship  and  now REHPViewModelData of Categroeis  column and BudgetAuthority Column with relationship Categories and Budget Authority Tables.Result table  in sperate categories columns and ButgetAuthority Columns. How to do new model design and coding thank.

Comment: Please make it readable by formatting it.

Comment: please help and readable edited by my question.